# A problem related to intermediate value property of continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Universal Chord Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem)

Let $f:[0,1] \to R$ be  a real valued continuous function satisfying $f(0)=f(1)$. Then using intermediate value theorem we know for every $n \in N$ there exist two point $a,b \in [0,1]$ at a distance $1/n$ satisfying $f(a)=f(b)$.

Now my question is, for every $r\in [0,1]$ is it possible to find two points $a,b\in [0,1]$ at a distance $r$, satisfying $f(a)=f(b)$ provided $f:[0,1] \to R$ be  a real valued continuous function satisfying $f(0)=f(1)$.

as there is a counterexample for $r>1/2$, please consider the case when $r<1/2$.

Comment: @martin sorry martin but i was not aware of the universal chord theorem. And thanks for your references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $r=\frac23$ and 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\mathrm{if\ }x\le \frac13\\
1-2x &\mathrm{if\ } \frac13<x<\frac23\\
x-1 &\mathrm{if\ }x\ge\frac23
\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have one doubt. For $r< 1/2$ will we be able to produce counterexample.