# how prove $\exists a,b$ that satisfied in following conditions $0 <a\leq b\leq 1, b-a=\frac12, \text{ and }f(a)=f(b)$

Tags: analysis, contest-math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Universal Chord Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem)

let $f:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb R$  be continuous and $f(0)=f(1)$how prove $\exists a,b$ that satisfied in following conditions $$1)0<a\leq b\leq 1$$$$2)b-a=\frac12$$$$f(a)=f(b)$$ thanks in advance

Comment: The second condition implies $a < b$, contradicting the first condition. Did you mean $0 < a < b \leq 1$ instead of the first condition?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem) is a related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Define $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{2})-f(x)$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Then show that $g(a)=0$ for some $a\in(0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Then let $b=a+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: thanks sir your hint help me to prove it