# Property of a continuous function with $f(0)=f(2)$

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,2]$ such that $f(0)=f(2)$.We have to show that there is a real number $c$ in the interval $[1,2]$, such that $f(c)=f(c-1)$.

I am completely lost on this question. I have tried fiddling with Rolles theorem and the Mean Value Theorem but it hasn't worked.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem) and its "linked' section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$, and the fact that it is continuous. What values does it take at $x=1$ and $x=2$ ? Consider applying Intermediate Value theorem of continuous functions.

Comment: Right! How did  you hit upon this idea?

Comment: @Sawarnik I think there are nice explanations of the intuition behind it in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612462/intuition-for-the-universal-chord-theorem

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$h(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$$
then $h$ is continuous on the interval $[1,2]$ and $h(1)h(2)=-(f(1)-f(0))^2\le0$ so by the intermediate value theorem there's $c\in[1,2]$ such that $h(c)=0$ which means $f(c)=f(c-1)$.