# Let $f: [0, 1]\rightarrow R$ be continuous and suppose that $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove there is $x$ such that $f(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: [0, 1]\rightarrow R$ be continuous and suppose that $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove
that for each positive integer $n$ there is an $x$ in $[0, 1 - \frac{1}{n}]$ such that
$f(x) = f(x + \frac{1}{n}$).

Without loss of generality, take $f(0)=f(1)=0$. I have been able to show that if $f(x)\ge 0$ or $f(x)\le 0$ the statement is true. It actually isn't that difficult to show. The trick is to define $g_n(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)$, on $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ then notice that $g(0)=f(\frac{1}{n})$ and $g(1-\frac{1}{n}) = -f(1-\frac{1}{n})$. We want to exclude the cases where $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ and $f(1-\frac{1}{n})=0$ since that will immediately prove our statement. Using our condition $f(x)\ge 0$ and $f(x)\le 0$ and applying intermediate value theorem, we deduce that there's some $c$ such that $g_n(c)=0$.

When we don't have the condition $f(x)\ge 0$ and $f(x)\le 0$, we could have continuous function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})\cdot f(1-\frac{1}{n}) = -|f(\frac{1}{n})\cdot f(1-\frac{1}{n})|$ (this is a long way of saying they have different sign). Notice that the method I described in the paragraph above can be extended to any interval $[a,b]$ if $b-a\ge \dfrac{1}{n}$. The main obstacle I face right now is that $f$ could have at least $n$ zeros such that the distance between any consecutive zeros the distance is at most $\frac{1}{n}$.

However, I have struggled with this problem for a while now and I have made little progress. I would appreciate some hints, but please don't post complete solutions.

Comment: Perhaps show your method for one of the cases you described and explain why the general case is more difficult.

Comment: Okay. I will do that soon

Comment: @tomasliam I just expanded my question.

Comment: I think some of your $f$'s are supposed to be $g_n$'s

Comment: @tomasliam thanks catching that!

Comment: A classic puzzle.  Next show that the numbers of the form $1/n$ are the only ones with this property.

Comment: @GEdgar could you be more specific when you say "this property"?

Comment: Did you search for duplicates? This has appeared many many times.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy When I was posting the problem it didn't show me anything relevant, but now I see there are duplicates. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, I think you should delete the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Would that get me banned?

Comment: Sorry, "this property" is the one in the title.  Let $0<a<1$ be any number not of the form $1/m$.  Then there is a function $f$ with $f(0)=f(1)$ but $f(x) \ne f(x+a)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @GEdgar Whoaa, that sounds a much stronger statement!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Universal Chord Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem) Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612462/intuition-for-the-universal-chord-theorem).

Comment: I saw an article in a magazine covering GEdgar's question, not too long ago. The function he talks of is not very difficult to construct.

Answer (score 5):

Let $g_n(x)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)$, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g_n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=f(1)-f(0)=0$$
Thus there exists $k$ such that $g_n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) g_n\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)\leqslant 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $g_n$ is continuous and there exists $x\in\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right]$ such that $g_n(x)=0$ using intermediate value theorem. Since $g_n$ is defined on $\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$, $x\in \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$.

Comment: Why are there downvotes? Could you who have downvoted explain the reason of your downvotes? I think the proof of Tuvasbien is correct, but if there are mistakes, could you tell me about them?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose on the contrary that no such $x$ exists. Then the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(x + 1/n)$ is continuous; WLOG, take $g$ to be strictly positive over $[0, \frac{n - 1}{n}]$. Then we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g(0) + g(1/n) + ... + g(\frac{n - 1}{n}) &= f(0) - f(1/n) + f(1/n) - f(2/n) + ... + f(\frac{n - 1}{n}) - f(1) \\
&= f(0) - f(1) \\
&= 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But this contradicts the fact that $g$ is strictly positive.