# Transformation of a continious function

Tags: continuity

Suppose that $f:[0,2\pi$] $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.

Show that there exists an $x\in[0,\pi$] such that $f(x)=f(x+\pi)$.

I simply have no idea where to start, any help would be appreciated.
I have run the transformation through the definition of continuity but I couldn't see that it helped at all.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(x) = f(x)-f(x+\pi)$. Then $$g(0) = f(0)-f(\pi)$$

and

$$g(\pi) = f(\pi)-f(2\pi) = f(\pi)-f(0) = -(f(0)-f(\pi)).$$

Do you see what this tells you?

Comment: It shows that $g(0)=-g(\pi)$ and so if $g(0)$ doesn't equal $0$, then using Intermediate value theorem there must be a point between $g(0)$ and $g(\pi)$ that equals $0$, but I am not sure if that is what you meant .

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I understand this may be a stupid question but how exactly does this help?

Comment: It says that there is a point $x$ where $g(x) = 0$ or in other words.. $f(x)-f(x+\pi) = 0$.

Comment: I see it now.You've been a great help, thank you.