# are there $x_{1},x_{2} \in [0,2]$ such that $x_{1}-x_{2}=1$ and $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$?

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ continuous at $[0,2]$ with $f(0)=f(2)$.Check if there are $x_{1},x_{2} \in [0,2]$ such that $x_{1}-x_{2}=1$ and $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$ . How can I do this?

Comment: Hint: Use the Intermediate Value theorem with a suitable function.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem) is a related problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+1)$. What can you say about $g(0)$ and $g(1)$?

Comment: $g(0)=-g(1)$ ,right?

Comment: @evinda: Consider the signs of $g(0)$ and $g(1)$, and the fact that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: We could use the Bolzano theorem,because $g$ is continuous at $[0,1]$ and $g(0)g(1)<0$.So we conclude that $g$ has at least one root $w$ at $[0,1]$,so $g(w)=0 \Rightarrow f(w)=f(w+1)$ ,right?But,could I also use the Intermediate value theorem?