# Show that $h(x) = h(x + \frac{1}{2013})$ for some x in $[0,1]$

Tags: proof-verification, contest-math

Edit: I very much appreciate alternate solutions to the problem, but I would also like to know if there are any problems or suggestions regarding the way I solved it.

This is a problem I'm attempting from a set of practice Putnam questions (it's also very similar to a problem in Spivak's *Calculus*.  I was wondering if there were any problems with my solution.

**Problem:**
Let $h(t)$ be a continuous function on the interval $[0, 1]$ such that $h(0) = h(1) = 0$.  Show that there exists a real number $x \in  [0, \frac{2012}{2013}]$ such that $h(x) = h(x + \frac{1}{2013})$.

**My attempt at a solution:**

I'm going to generalize it with the case $h(x) = h(x + \frac{1}{n})$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (assuming that won't cause any difficulties).

Let $$g(x) = h(x) - h(x + \frac{1}{n}) \text{ on } [0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$$

We now attempt to prove the problem by contradiction. Assume $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$ in $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$.Then $h(x) \neq h(x + \frac{1}{n})$ for all $x$ in $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$.Certainly $g$ is continuous on the interval, since $h$ is continuous on the interval, so by the intermediate value theorem, it cannot be both positive and negative on the interval (for if it were, then we would have $g(a) > 0$ and $g(b) < 0$ (or vice versa) on some interval, which would mean that there is some $c \in [a, b]$ such that $g(c) = 0$, which we are assuming is not true).  First we assume that $g(x) > 0$ on $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$.  If this were the case, then $h(x) > h(x + \frac{1}{n})$ on $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$. This implies that $h$ is always decreasing on $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$, which is not possible, since $h(0) = h(1)$.  If we assume the opposite case, that $g(x) < 0$ on $[0,\frac{n-1}{n}]$, then $h(x + \frac{1}{n}) > h(x)$ on $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$, which is also not possible, because it would mean $h$ is always increasing on $[0,\frac{n-1}{n}]$.  Since neither of these cases is possible, then $g(x)$ must equal $0$ at some point in $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$, so by extension, $h(x) = h(x + \frac{1}{n})$ for some $x \in [0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$. To solve the given problem, we simply let $n = 2013$.

Comment: Since $n$ is given, $h(x) > h(x + \frac{1}{n})$ doesn't mean $h$ is decreasing.

Comment: [Universal Chord Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem)

Comment: As @mfl says, the following conclusion is not valid: "This implies that $h$ is always decreasing...".

Comment: But if $g(x)>0$ on $[0,(n-1)/n]$, then $g(0)$ is positive, so $0=h(0)>h(1/n)$. And $g((n-1)/n)$ is positive, so $h((n-1)/n)>h(1)=0$. So $h$ is negative at $1/n$ and positive at $(n-1)/n$. Now $g(1/n)$ is positive, so $0>h(1/n)>h(2/n)$. And $g((n-2)/n)$ is positive, so $h((n-2)/n)>h((n-1)/n)>0$. So now $h$ is negative at $2/n$ and positive at $(n-2)/n$. See where this is going?

Comment: Yes, I see my faulty logic now. I'm assuming I'd have to deal with the possibility that h can increase between the natural numbers. As stated in the answers, it's clear to me now that such a condition isn't fully necessary. Perhaps more true to the original idea of the proof, I'm assuming it suffices to say: $g(0) > g(1/n) > ...> g(1)$, which is a clear contradiction.

Comment: My mistake. Those are supposed to be h, not g.

Comment: You say g is decreasing from 0 to n-1/n.  Okay, but you say that's impossible because g (1)=g (0). Well g can be decreasing from 0 to n-1/n but then jump right be to g(0) in the remaining n-1/n to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By contradiction, assume that:

$$
  \forall x \in \left[0, \frac{n-1}{n} \right] \; h(x) > h \left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

Then

$$
  h(0) > h \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) > h \left( \frac{2}{n} \right) > \dots > h(1)
$$

But $h(0) > h(1)$ is obviously false since $h(0) = h(1) = 0$, hence our assumption must be false, that is:

$$
 \exists x \in \left[0, \frac{n-1}{n} \right] : h(x) \leq h \left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

And with an analogous argument we can prove that:

$$
 \exists x \in \left[0, \frac{n-1}{n} \right] : h(x) \geq h \left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

This proves that the continuous function

$$
 g(x) = h(x) - h \left( x + \frac{1}{n} \right)
$$

assumes both positive and negative values on the interval (or is constant), and hence it must have a zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x)=h(x)-h\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$g(0)=-h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$g\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Because $g(0)$ and $g\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ have opposite signs...

Answer (score 0):

Let:
$$g:x\in[0,1-\dfrac{1}{n}]\longmapsto h\left(x+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-h(x)$$
Evaluate $g$  in $n$ different points:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl} g(0)&=&{\color{green}{h\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}}-0 \\
g\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)&=&{\color{blue}{h\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)}}-{\color{green}{h\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}}\\
g\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)&=&h\left(\dfrac{3}{n}\right)-{\color{blue}{h\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)}}\\
\dots & = & \dots  \\
g\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)  & = & 0-h\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \\ 
\end{array}\right.$$

Let's sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)=0$$

So $g$ is either the zero function, or has strictly positive and strictly negative values. Conclude with continuity of $g$ and the intermediate value theorem!