# A problem in real valued function on compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

If $f$ be a real valued continuous function defined on $[0,2]$ such that $f(0)=f(2),$ then prove that there exist a $ x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f(x+1).$

I tried in the following way,

Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0)=f(2)$, any line parallel to $x-$axis meets $f$ at least two points. Is this the correct way?

How to proceed further?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem) and the posts in its "linked" section.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the intermediate value theorem.
Let $$g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$$

Then 
$$g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$$ and 
$$g(1)=f(2)-f(1)=-g(0)$$

Now if $g(0)=0$ we are done with $x=0$ otherwise $g(0)\neq 0$ and by intermediate value there is $x\in (0,1)$ such that $g(x)=0$. And we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ the function defined by

$$h(t)=f(t+1)-f(t)$$
then $h$ is continuous and

$$h(1)h(0)=(f(2)-f(1))(f(1)-f(0))=-(f(1)-f(0))^2\le0$$
so by the intermediate value theorem there's $x\in[0,1]$ such that $h(x)=0$.