# Proof of parallel chord theorem

Tags: continuity

Where can i find a correct proof of the following theorem of H.Hopf:

For every continuous curve $L$ in the plane with endpoints $A$ and $B$ such that distance $\vert AB \vert = 1$, and for any natural number $n$, there exists a chord (meaning a straight segment with endpoints on $L$) that is parallel to $AB$ and whose length  equals $1/n$.

Comment: I can't find the proof, but it is in "H. Hopf, Uber die Sehen ebener Kontinuen und die
Schleifen geschlossener Wege, Commentarii Mathematici
Helvetici IX (1936-37), 303-319". If I remember correctly.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276889/proving-that-there-exists-a-horizontal-chord-with-length-1-n-for-a-continuous?rq=1).