# If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)$ then there exists $ x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{n})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)$, then there exists $ x\in [0,1]$ such that  $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{n})$, where $n$ is any natural number.

Let $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)$ on $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$. Now, $f$ is continuous function on closed interval.So, it must attain its bounds. Let $m$ be minima at $c_1 \in [0,1]$ and $M$ be maxima at $c_2 \in [0,1]$.

Now if $c_1,c_2 \in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$, apply IVT to $g(x)$ on $[c_1,c_2]$. 
If $c_1$ or $c_2 \in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$, apply IVT to $[c_1,c_1-\frac{1}{n}]$ or 
$[c_2,c_2-\frac{1}{n}]$ respectively. If
 $c_1,c_2$ both do not belong to $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$, then apply IVT to $g$ on $[c_1-\frac{1}{n},c_2-\frac{1}{n}]$.

Is this proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: $c_1,c_2$ are definitely in $[0,1].$ Do you mean "If $c_1,c_2$ both do not belong to $\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right],\cdots$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews sorry I edited it.

Comment: You don't need to appeal to the maximum value theorem here. Just the IVT does it.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin How only IVT is sufficient? Can you please show your proof? Or give me some hint.

Comment: Consider $g$ at the endpoints of its domain.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin If we apply IVT to  $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)$ on $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$, we get $g(0)=f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)$ and $g(1-\frac{1}{n})=f(0)-f(1-\frac{1}{n})$. Now how to proceed?

Comment: If $g\ne 0$, $g$ must always have the same sign, and then $f(0)=f(1)$ is impossible.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin ohh now i got it. Tnx.

Comment: Cf also elder math.SE stuff: [Universal chord theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/universal-chord-theorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see what your last paragraph leads to. And you must use the fact that $n\in \Bbb N$ because if $r\in (0,1)\setminus \{1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ then there is a continuous $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ with $f(0)=f(1),$ such that $f(x)\ne f(x+r)$ for all $x\in [0,1-r].$

I saw this in American Mathematical Monthly. The title was (approximately?) The Theorem Of The Horizontal Chord. The idea is that $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}g(j/n)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f((j+1)/n)-f(j/n)=$$ $$=f(1)-f(0)=0  $$ so the members of $\{g(j/n):j=0,...,n-1\}$ cannot be all positive or all negative, so by the IVT, $g(x)$ must be $0$ for some $x\in [0,1-1/n].$

Comment: Thanks. Very nice and elegant answer. By the way, in my last paragraph after applying IVT on $g$, $g$ will be negative at one end point and positive at other. So $g(x)=0$ somewhere between.

Comment: Yep,and this makes clear why other $\epsilon>0$ not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ do not work.

Comment: To the proposer: I still can't follow your last paragraph and I don't see what would differ in it if you replaced $1/n$ with an arbitrary $r\in (0,1).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet sorry. Actually my proof is incorrect.